# C# WebBrowser - act on javascript window.close(); (act= override close WinForm window)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have an web application containing a javascript block which wants to close the opened window. This is done by `window.close();`

I'm hosting this application in a `C#` WebBrowser WinForm project. When the javascript code `window.close();` gets called, I'm getting a MessageBox question from the WebBrowser. This says 'The Webpage is trying to close the window...'. If clicked yes, the WinForm window will close.

My issue is that I would like to allow javascript to close this window, I don't want this warning message to appear.

Any ideas? I've tried overriding `WinForm FormClosing event`, but this message happens directly in the WebBrowser. I have also overrided `WndProc` in `WM_PARENTNOTIFY (0x210), on WM_DESTROY`. However this is called after the question is answered in the WebBrowser warning.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these for window closing in javascript works great:

```
window.open('', '_self');
window.close();
```